# How do I make this macro create a new sheet after comparing values to a set variable?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am writing a macro that splits out data to another sheet after
comparing values in column A to a set variable.

Column A has all Work Order numbers. I need the macro to create
a new sheet for each new work order, and copy all lines to that sheet.
It needs to name the sheet with a concatenation of the value
found in column A and Column B, and then copy all rows associated with
that Work Order to the new sheet.

[image]

The prefix is the Work Order. Prefix 12581 should get its own sheet, named
12581-4, and prefix 12695 should get its own sheet named 12695-4.
All rows for 12581 should be copied into the sheet named 12581.

This needs to be a loop since there are 39000 rows to sift through.

I thought I'd need to declare a variable for the Work Order/prefix
and have the macro compare it to the values in column A. If the value in column
A does not match the variable it would create a new sheet and copy over all columns
associated with that Work Order.

My code so far:

```
Sub SortDataByWOxyz()

Option Explicit

Dim Variable_One as Integer
Dim Variable_Two As Integer
Dim cell As Range
Dim Sht_name As String
Dim intLastRow As Integer
Dim intSuffix As Integer

Set Variable_One = 0
Set intSuffix = .Range("b2", .Range("b2").End(xlDown))

intLastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RowsCount
Set cell = Range ("a2:a" & intLastRow) 'this is so the macro
doesn't keep trying to process rows without values



For Each cell In Sheets(1).Range("A2:F39986") 'Ok, another issue
is that I can't be certain the range of every report I am applying
this macro to. Is there some way to make the range globally applicable, like:
Dim SourceRange As Range
Set SourceRange= .Range("a2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))


If cell.Value <> Variable_One Then

'Grab prefix - suffix
'Create sheet with sheet name
'Copy data

Sheets.Add.Name = Range(a2:a" & intSuffix).value
cell.EntireRow.CopyDestination:=Sheets(Sht_name).Range("a" & cell.Row)

Else: cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets(Sht_name).Range("a" & cell.Row)
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what your actual question is: To create a sheet? To copy data from one sheet to another? To loop over all rows of a sheet? There are more than enough answers on SO and elsewhere to all of these.

Comment: Some remarks to your code: **(1)** use meaningfull names **(2)** Indent your code **(3)** `Option explicit` needs to be at the top of the code **(4)** use `Long`, not `Integer`, else you risk numeric overflow **(5)** `.Range` (with leading dot) will only work if you have a `with`-clause **(6)** Do not use `Else: ...` - remove the `":"` and put the statement on the next line.

Comment: If your code is failing to run, is it because of the missing quote on `Sheets.Add.Name = Range(a2:a"` which should be `Sheets.Add.Name = Range("a2:a"`? Note how the text is white, turns pink for the literal string, then never returns to white (or blue) for the rest of the code. I hope that's just a copy/pasteo error when putting the code up here for review.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: To clarify: I need the macro to create a new sheet every time a new work order number is found in column A. I need the sheet to be named the work order number. Then it needs to copy all rows with that work order number into the newly created sheet. Yes it needs to loop this through all rows in the main sheet

Comment: And yes I have looked on SO/ MrExcel/ Microsoft forums.